# Work around Sequelize’s unique constraints in belongsToMany associations

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in my project. These are the two models:

```
const User = db.define('user', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING
})
const Product = db.define('product', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  price: Sequelize.INTEGER
})
```

Now users can purchase products and I have associations setup like below:

```
Product.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProducts'})
User.belongsToMany(Product, {through: 'UserProducts'})
```

I also have this UserProducts table with an additional column.

```
const UserProducts = db.define('UserProducts', {
  status: Sequelize.STRING
})
```

Sequelize creates a composite key with combination of userId and productId and will only allow one record with a combination of userId and productId. So, for example, userId 2 and productId 14.

This is a problem for me because sometimes people want to purchase multiple times. I need one of the following scenarios to work:

1. Don't use the composite key and instead have a completely new auto-increment column used as key in UserProducts.
2. Instead of making key with userId and productId alone, allow me to add one more column into the key such as the `status` so that unique key is a combination of the three.

I do want to use the associations as they provide many powerful methods, but want to alter the unique key to work in such a way that I can add multiple rows with the same combination of user id and product id.

And since my models/database is already running, I will need to make use of migrations to make this change.

Any help around this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well the relation that you really need then is `1:N` - `User:Products`. M:N works like that, always a comination of 2 keys. Now if you want to keep your model like that and use 3 keys, you have to change manually on the database and add the constraint, Sequelize does not support that.

Comment: @Ellebkey can you help explain how I can do this manually?

Comment: I'm not very sure to do it, You could use `ALTER TABLE dbo.yourtablename
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_yourtablename UNIQUE(column1, column2, column3);` But this only create your 3 field restriction, still you will have 2 primary keys on the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Belongs-To-Many creates a unique key when the primary key is not present on through model.

Since you also have additional property in your `UserProducts` table, you need to define the model for `UserProducts` and then tell the sequelize to use that model instead of creating its own

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING
}, { sequelize })

class Product extends Model {}
ProjProductect.init({
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, { sequelize })

class UserProducts extends Model {}
UserProducts.init({
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  status: DataTypes.STRING
}, { sequelize })

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProducts })
Product.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProducts })
```

refer: [Sequelize v4 belongsToMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

**UPDATE**

since you are using v3 and already have a model created for your `UserProducts` table use following snippet

```
UserProducts = db.define('UserProducts', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  status: DataTypes.STRING
})
```

Comment: I believe this will work. But because my model is already there and I have data in it, how can I use migrations to make this change in primary key? Another worry I have is - since my table already has data, how will the auto-increment work on the existing records?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to add primary key using migration. I suggest you to try this `migration.addColumn('Table', 'column', { type: STRING, primaryKey : true });` 
  also refer to this issue on github [#3918](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3918)

Answer (score 18):

If anyone else is having problems in **v5 of Sequelize**, it is not enough to specify a primary key on the 'through' model.
You have to explicitly set the unique property on the through model.

```
User.belongsToMany(Product, { through: { model: UserProducts, unique: false } });
Product.belongsToMany(User, { through: { model: UserProducts, unique: false } });
```

Comment: unique: false is not working. It still shows a single child even if multiple duplicate children are present. Do you have a fix?

Comment: @AayushTaneja just in case you were doing the same mistake I was, it is `{ through: { model: UserProducts, unique: false } }` NOT `{ through: UserProducts, unique: false }`

Answer (score 0):

Since setting explicitly  the unique property on the through model is not working **in v6**, the only solution i found is to define the 3 parts of the association this way :

```
User.hasMany(UserProducts);
UserProducts.belongsTo(User);

Product.hasMany(UserProducts);
UserProducts.belongsTo(Product);
```

You can then create your models and associations :

```
const user = await User.create(user_data);
const product = await Product.create(product_data);
const up = await UserProduct.create(up_data);
await up.setUser(user);
await up.setProduct(product);
```

If anyone has a better solution, I would be happy to know it

Comment: What dialect are you using? Neo answer works on MySQL and Postgres with v6 :-)

Comment: @Adrien seems like I was tired, it actually works on Postgres