# Sequelize junction table, how to force creating a new row and not updating an old one

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for postgreSQL with nodejs. I've a junction table with 4 columns (id, user_id, offer_id, store_id).

I realized that when I insert value already present in the row of junction table, this row is updated and not created.

For example: Junction table contains the following row: user_id = 3, offer_id = 2 , store_id = 1, if I perform a query with the same data, then this row will be updated and not created as expected.
**I need always to get a new row created.**

[following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322411/work-around-sequelize-s-unique-constraints-in-belongstomany-associations/58439584#58439584)

I've updated my models and association, but it still  not working:

```
const addRefund = await offer.addUserRefunds(clientId,{
      through: {
        store_id: storeId
      },            
});
```

association of relation are as follow

```
//offre - utilisateur - remboursement client
Offer.belongsToMany(User,{
    through: {
        model: Refund,
        unique: false
    },
    as: 'userRefunds'
});

User.belongsToMany(Offer,{
    through: {
        model: Refund,
        unique: false
    },
    as: 'offerRefunds'
});
```

models are as follow

refund model

```
class Refund extends Model{
}

Refund.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    store_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
},{
    sequelize,
    tableName:'refund'
});
module.exports = Refund;
```

user model

```
class User extends Model{
}

User.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    active_account: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    active_professional: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
},{
    sequelize,
    tableName:'user'
});
module.exports = User;
```

offer model

```
class Offer extends Model{
}

Offer.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    presentation: DataTypes.STRING,
    global_refund: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    individual_refund: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    is_active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    image_url: DataTypes.STRING,
    user_id:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    store_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
},{
    sequelize,
    tableName:'offer'
});
module.exports = Offer;
```

SQL query generated by Sequelize (this entry already exist in junction table)

```
Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "offer_id", "store_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "offer_id" AS "OfferId", "user_id" AS "UserId" FROM "refund" AS "Refund" WHERE "Refund"."offer_id" = 2 AND "Refund"."user_id" IN (4);
Executing (default): UPDATE "refund" SET "store_id"=$1,"updated_at"=$2 WHERE "offer_id" = $3 AND "user_id" = $4
```

SQL query generated by Sequelize with a new entry (not present in the junction table)

```
Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "offer_id", "store_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "offer_id" AS "OfferId", "user_id" AS "UserId" FROM "refund" AS "Refund" WHERE "Refund"."offer_id" = 3 AND "Refund"."user_id" IN (4);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "refund" ("store_id","created_at","updated_at","offer_id","user_id") VALUES ('2','2022-07-07 07:45:08.239 +00:00','2022-07-07 07:45:08.239 +00:00',3,4) RETURNING "user_id","offer_id","store_id","created_at","updated_at";
```

thanks in advance for helping me solving this problem

brgds
Cyrille

Comment: Please show models and associations

Comment: Hello Anatoly, I add models and associations. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you also show the SQL OUTPUT after executing `addUserRefunds`>?

Comment: I add SQL query generated by Sequelize.

Comment: It seems you need auto-generated primary keys for all tables and models.

Comment: My sql table already have a auto-generated key: id" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY.  @Anatoly

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a 3-way junction table your only option would be to use `hasMany` with `Refund` table like this:

```js
Offer.hasMany(Refund,{
    as: 'UserRefunds'
});
Refund.belongsTo(User);
Refund.belongsTo(Store);
User.hasMany(Refund,{
    as: 'OfferRefunds'
});
...
// get an offer instance somehow
const offer = Offer.findOne({
// some conditions
})
await offer.createUserRefund({
  clientId,
  storeId
})
```

Comment: I try your solution, but Offer.createRefund() always generates this error: "createRefund is not a function". I will keep working on it, and let you know if I succeed.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like it should be `offer.createUserRefund` because of a custom alias.

Comment: I corrected my answer